# How to use reset(), .value, and other DOM keys in typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-2017

So I'm using typescript for basic funkcionality, however it refuses to compile because of the following error

```
src/app.ts:46:38 - error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

46   return document.getElementById(id).value
```

I have es2017 as a target, therefore I have read that it includes dom libraries, however I still cannot make it work.

Is there a way to use .value, reset() and other dom methods or at least make compiler ignore this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `document.getElementById(id)`, TypeScript can't know for sure that the element returned will of the type `HTMLInputElement`. You will have to use [an assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) if you want to infor typescript about what your html will contain (and therefore dom will return):

```
return (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement).value
```